# Safest way to guard against missing and undefined parameters?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is passed an argument from a network call and I want to guard against these arguments when they are `null`, missing, or otherwise undefined. Can I simply default each property to `null` and then check against them being `null` as my guard? Or is there a safer way?

```
exports.pushNotify = functions.https.onCall((data, _context) => {
    const recipientUserId = data.recipientUserId || null;
    const senderUserId = data.senderUserId || null;
    const senderName = data.senderName || null;
    const messageText = data.messageText || null;

    if (recipientUserId != null && senderUserId != null && senderName != null && messageText != null) {
        // proceed
    } else {
        // terminate
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `truthiness` is what you're checking against for your arguments, you can clean this code up with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) and truthy evaluation. That would look like this:

```js
    exports.pushNotify = functions.https.onCall((data, _context) => {
        const { recipientUserId, senderUserId, senderName, messageText } = data;
        const valid = recipientUserId && senderUserId && senderName && messageText;
        if (!valid) {
            // terminate
        }

        // proceed
    });
```

A simple way to think about a `truthy` value is that it is not `null`, `undefined`, empty string, or 0. See a table of all truthy/falsy values here: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/.

Comment: Because I'm only dealing with strings, I can safely check for truthiness so I will do that. However, out of curiosity, what if one of the properties is a boolean and I want to guard against it being `null` or undefined? Would `const someBool = data.someBool || null;` do that?

Comment: @kidcoder You'll find lots of different opinions on this, but IMO - `data.someBool != null` is a good way to handle those cases. Notice that it's `!=` and not `!==`. `!=` is a weak check that coerces `undefined` and `null` to behave the same way.

The other way I'd prefer personally is `typeof data.someBool === 'boolean'`

Comment: @kidcoder Since you're talking about booleans and defaulting them in a single line, maybe: `const someBool = (typeof data.someBool === 'boolean') ? data.someBool : undefined`. This feels a bit clunky, but not too bad.

Comment: Thanks for the help! And, again just out of curiosity, is the way I handled it in my example safe? Would my code guard against `null`, undefined, and empty strings?

Comment: @kidcoder Happy to help! `value != null` will return true for an empty string. In your code, then, empty strings would have passed through to the 'proceed' block.

Comment: So the safest way then would be to check type first using `typeof` and then check for truthiness, correct?

Comment: Close -- `if (someString) { ... }` will be checked for `truthiness` only, and the type is pretty much irrelevant. Using `typeof` to check for proper types is a more verbose but often 'safer' way to confirm you have expected values. I'd recommend playing around in a JavaScript console and using the equality table I linked in my answer just to get a better idea of how this works

Comment: I deleted the comment before you posted this answer because I realized truthiness doesn't check for types. `if (typeof someString === "string" && someString) { ... }` is what I'm going with. Thanks again for the help, you've been great.